# How to use multiple supply options in the easiest way for STM32?

Tags: power-supply, stm32, switching, ftdi, dual-supply

I designed a custom board with STM32, ADC, and RS422 transceivers.
The estimated current consumption of all the IC on the circuit is not more than 200 mA on 3.3 V.

in the operational mode, the board should be powered with a power supply with an output of 5 V with enough current.
I want to add options when the software engineer works on my board that he doesn't need to connect the power supply, and could use in the power from USB which in any case is connected for debugging purposes.

The main problem is that when we set the board to the system we are supposed to use the USB connection to the computer for debugging **only** anyway, but the voltage from the USB is **not** required due to safety issues, and the voltage should be received from the power source.

Simply put:
In the lab for debugging and bringing up work - use the power from the USB and communications to the computer.

In an operational system - power from the power source and communications to the computer without power from the USB. How to do it?
[image]

Comment: That is interesting problem, because from the USB point of view, the board is either bus-powered or self-powered, and in both cases the FTDI connections will be different. Have a look of you can simply set FTDI to self-powered and use diodes to OR the supplies together.

Comment: THE FTDI POWERED BY 3.3V the voltage from USB/power supply go to LDO with 5V

Comment: Sounds like a job for a jumper (and some diodes).

Comment: Take a look in the schematics of the stm32 nucleo boards. They all have the option to either be powered from USB, 5V, 3.3V or even 7-12V source by setting a jumper. If you don't want to use a jumper, try searching for power multiplexers.

Comment: Why not showing your powerpath? Would be easier to make suggestions.